# incrementar evento depois de um determinado tempo

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Estou fazendo uma aplicação que simula um marcador de ponto, e precisaria que ele incremente a próxima marcação somente depois de 5 minutos, fiz alguns testes com *setTimeout*, mas não cheguei no que precisava.
A aplicação faz as marcações, mas não tem o temporizador de tempo(5 minutos).

**js:**

```
    var qtd = document.getElementById("dataTime");

function getTime(){

  var data = new Date();
  var full_time = data.getHours() + ":" + data.getMinutes() + ":" + data.getSeconds();

  var dataCompleta = full_time;

  while (qtd < 4){
   document.getElementById("horaMarcada").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<span id="dataTime">'+ dataCompleta +' </span>');
   qtd++;
   return false;
  }
}
```

**html:**

```
<button onclick="getTime()">Marcar</button>
```

Comment: não seria melhor vc guardar a hora no banco de dados e ir verificando a diferença com o *setTimeout*? assim ficaria mais confiável e mais seguro para sua aplicação.

Comment: a principio pretendo guardar as marcações com localStorage

Comment: Vc quer 3 marcações ou 4?

Comment: 4 marcações, a primeira no ato e as outras 3 somente depois de 5 minutos, se a pessoa clicar antes de 5 minutos vou apresentar uma mensagem dizendo que somente depois de 5 minutos

Comment: obs: e as outras 3, cada uma somente depois de 5 minutos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É preciso alterar o `<span id="dataTime">` para `<span class="dataTime">` porque estão sendo criados elementos com o mesmo `id`, o que já é errado.

Com `class` você consegue contar a quantidade de elementos em tempo real, dispensando a *auto-incrementação* com `qtd++`.

Ao clicar no botão, o atributo `onclick` muda para um `alert`, e após 5 minutos, volta ao normal.

Você pode colocar tudo dentro da função na ordem abaixo:

```js
function getTime(){

   document.querySelector("button").setAttribute("onclick","alert('Aguarde 5 minutos!')");
   
   var data = new Date();
   var full_time = data.getHours() + ":" + data.getMinutes() + ":" + data.getSeconds();
   var dataCompleta = full_time;
   
   document.getElementById("horaMarcada").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<span class="dataTime">'+ dataCompleta +' </span>');
   var qtd = document.getElementsByClassName("dataTime").length;

   if(qtd < 4){
      setTimeout(function(){
         document.querySelector("button").setAttribute("onclick","getTime()");
      }, 300000);
   }else{
      document.querySelector("button").disabled = true;
      console.log("fim");
   }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="getTime()">Marcar</button>
<div id="horaMarcada"></div>
```

Comment: Dvd, fiz um teste numa arquivo apartado, mas não esta rolando o temporizador

Comment: ta fazendo o loop, mas não faz a pausa de 5 minutos para a próxima marcação, mudei para 300000

Comment: dvd, estou usando igual, criei um JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/josecarlosdw/0ndv7hpp/

Comment: dvd, veja meu resultado https://imgur.com/ZObAdNs

Comment: @josecarlos Agora acho que foi. Abs!

Comment: dvd, exatamente isso, muito obrigado! abs

Comment: @josecarlos não deixe de marcar a resposta como certa. Abs!

Comment: Marcado, meu caro. abs!